# How can I show only final results which are exactly matched with the search function in AJAX DataTable?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables

```
        var table = $('#customer-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('api.users') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'title', name: 'title'},
                {data: 'date', name: 'date'},   
            ]
        });
   </script>
```

```
`Route::get('/apiUsers','UserController@apiUsers')->name('api.users');`
```

```
     public function apiUsers()
        {
            $customer = Customer::all();
    
            return Datatables::of($customer)
                ->addColumn('action', function($customer){
                    return'<a onclick="editForm('. $customer->id .')" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit </a> ' .
                        '<a onclick="deleteData('. $customer->id .')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete </a>';
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])->make(true);
        }
```

```
    <script src=" {{ asset('assets/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }} "></script>
```

Above is the code. May I know how can I show only the matching results instead of the whole database showing at first and then only the search results ? I have included the datatables script used as well. Thank you!

Comment: (1) Do you really need to use `serverSide: true`? Do you have such a large volume of data that the browser cannot handle it all? (2) If you _do_ need to use `serverSide: true` (because of data volumes), then are you familiar with how it is intended to be used? You should never need to have "_the whole database showing at first_". Server-side processing means the server should only ever send one page of results back to the DataTable at a time. The server is responsible for _all_ pagination, filtering and sorting logic. The DataTable simply tells the server what the user has asked to see.

Comment: See the PHP script (just for a simple example) used in [this official example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) - and see the related PHP data handling script [here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php). The official server-side processing guide is [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).